# optaplanner for calculating best discount

Tags: shopping-cart, drools, rules, optaplanner

I'm looking to use optaplanner to help calculate the best discount for a user buying a list of items  (e.g. A Shopping Cart).

Does this sound like a good idea?  Has any tried it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Consider:**

- I have a user wanting to buy a number of different items
- There are a number of Promotional Discounts available to this customer including: Percentage Discount and Buy-one-get-one-free on a number of the items

  -
- Each discount may only apply to some of the items
- Each item can only have one Promotion applied
- But each Promotion may be applied to multiple items.  The same Percentage Discount may be available to multiple items
- Applying each Promotion in different orders may result in a different total discount

**Goal** : I want to identify which Promotions applied in a certain order will give the user the greatest discount.

I have looked at both drools-expert (considering the brute force option) and optaplanner.  With optaplanner I do not see how I can do the following:

- Take into account that a Promotion may apply to multiple items
- Discount gained from a Promotion may differ depending on the state of the basket (i.e. which promotions have already been applied) when it is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. It allows the same promotion to be used on multiple items. Add a hard constraint that a buy-3-get-1 needs

```
class ItemAssignment {

  Item item;

  @PlanningVariable(nullable = true, ...)
  Promotion promotion;

}
```

Add a hard constraint for promotions that can only be used once. Add a soft constraint to activate a promotion that requires 3 items to be bought. I 'd do an insertLogical(new Discount) in that soft constraint, so the other rules can become smart enough as to which promotions have already been applied.

I am a bit in doubt if metaheuristics are the best approach for this, presuming that your problem is very small. Unless someone's buying more than 10 items at a time, I think brute force (implemented in optaplanner) or branch&bound (not yet implemented in optaplanner) might be a better choice...

Comment: Many thanks for your response Geoffrey.  I'll take a look at post my findings.